# WSAGetLastError returns 10038 while trying to get data using Telnet

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, telnet

I have a program sends data using telnet. By using putty i can get data.

But in my code i use same conenction prefs ( Same ip = 127.0.0.1, Same port = 27021)

But i get WSAENOTSOCK ( 10038 ) error.

Here is my code:

```
 WSADATA WSAData;
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
SOCKET sock;
WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &WSAData );


sock = WSASocket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0, 0, 0 );
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
sin.sin_port = htons( 27021 );


bind( sock, ( SOCKADDR * )&sin, sizeof( sin ) );
listen( sock, SOMAXCONN );
int sin_len=sizeof(sin);

while( true )

   {
    SOCKET tmp = accept( sock, NULL, NULL );
    char buff[ 1024 ];

int result = recv(tmp, buff, 1024, 0);

 std::cout<<buff<<" "<<result<<" "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    closesocket( tmp );
}
return( 0 );
}
```

It returns -1 as result and 10038 as wsagetlasterror.

EDIT: If I use sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); i get error codes but if I use sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1") no data received.

Comment: Does your `tmp` hold a valid socket, or it is `INVALID_SOCKET`?

Comment: Socket tmp = accept( sock , NULL, NULL);

Comment: The code is missing required error checking to verify that the bind() and listen() functions succeeded.  You postpone it too long and then of course can no longer figure out why recv() failed.  The firewall is a likely reason.

Comment: my problem is about binding. Is there any different way to bind TCP to TELNET?